# new git user using netbeans support unable to pull latest commit from remote repository

Tags: git, netbeans

I am a new GIT user, using the built in NetBeans support on win7. I have made some changes to my project files on a different computer, and committed them to the remote repo.  When I try to pull this latest version from my remote repository, I am getting the following error:

```
 ==[IDE]== Nov 13, 2012 11:35:27 PM Pulling...
 git pull bitbucket.org:kcsmith/b1.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
 No update
 Merge Result: Failed
 Merge of HEAD with origin/master failed because of these files:
 C:\wamp\www\path\to\file
```

how can I pull the latest version to the second computer?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure. But I'm pretty confident your trouble come from untracked file/changes in your working directory.

First, checkout the status of your working directory `git status`. If there's files listed, you need to add them (`git add -A`) and commit them (`git commit`) before you can pull. (*On a side note, instead of commiting, you could stash them*)

Once this is done and that `git status` show no files, you can pull the remote repository.

This behaviour prevent you from losing unsaved work during a merge process (as `pull` aliases a `fetch` following by a `merge`).

Comment: In NB: `git status` = `Git > Show Changes`.

Comment: Simon - You were right - would you mind explaining how you knew? Also Thank you madth3

Comment: Well, your Git integrated in netbeans don't have usual error message, but I was able to figure out some stuff. As I knew `pull` was a `fetch` following by a `merge`, I knew from your error messages your trouble wasn't in configuration as you had no error related to fetching the data. So, as it was written trouble about a merge, I just figured out the most probable cause for merge rejection was unstaged changes (as otherwise you'd have a merge conflict - but in your case it was only aborted). That's all

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. I'm guessing you're running git in Netbeans.
Please try to run the command in git shell.
You'll see the difference.