# git merge of head with origin/master failed because of these files in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, merge, conflict

We are working with Netbeans and sometimes get an error when pulling/pushing from git

**git merge of head with origin/master failed because of these files:
".../Filename.java"**

What can we do? How to solve this in netbeans?
We tried everything
 -> commit -> pull - same error
 -> commit -> push - same error

no windows showing up where we can resolve the conflicts.

**Edit:** When I do: git pull with the git shell, then it works, the file will show me the conflict...

But if I do the git pull via netbeans, netbeans doesnt show me anything, it keeps the file as it is without putting

```
<<<<<< HEAD:file.java
blablabla
========
blabla
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.java
```

inside.

Comment: Use the git command line and find out what is really going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd guess that file wasn't tracked, and you created it at the same time another one created it and commited it to your remote.

I'd suggest you to create a `stash`, `pull` changes, and then `stash pop`. It would probably create a conflict (as you're saying), but it can be addressed with Netbeans' merge editor.

Just resolve the conflict and you're done.

Alternatively, you can commit your file locally, and then `fetch` + `rebase` onto `origin/master` (or whichever your remote branch is). You'll get the conflict again, it's almost the same as the first option.

Comment: so in other words: Add -> Commit -> Pull -> Push instead of Add -> Commit -> Push -> Pull, right?

Comment: @Delta458 yeah, I think. Make sure to check any conflicts when you `pull`. You should resolve any.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem. I'm guessing you're running git in Netbeans.
Please try to run the command in git shell.
You'll see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I just recently had this same issue with not being able to merge pulls.  I'm doing everything in the proper sequence, but when pulling changes after a particular user made a change it would refuse.  I copied the command the Netbeans was sending and pasted it into a command line window.  Despite blowing up in Netbeans it performs perfectly at doing the merge from the command line.  Then I was able to push just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans, before doing any pull or push actions, use Git > Show Changes to see if there are any uncommitted changes. Once you have resolved these you should be able to push/pull without the error.

See more at: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373330/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373330/new-git-user-using-netbeans-support-unable-to-pull-latest-commit-from-remote-rep)