# GIT : Merge of HEAD with origin/master failed because of these files

Tags: git, netbeans, merge, netbeans-7, bitbucket

I have this problem with my project when I pull it :

```
git pull https://bitbucket.org/****************/***********.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
No update
Merge Result: Failed
Merge of HEAD with origin/master failed because of these files:
C:\wamp\www\PFASymfony_project\src\PFA\SIGBundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig

==[IDE]== 9 juin 2013 20:45:44 Pulling... finished.
```

How do I resolve this ?

I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.3

P.S : I'm a newbie on Git.

Comment: Did you do a "git status" to see if you have anything checked out? If so, perhaps you would do "git stash" before the pull. You would still need to merge your checkout, but you would see current state of origin/master, that may help.

Comment: "git status" doesn't give anything new. How do we do a "git stash" on NetBeans ? By the way, origin/master contains changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373330/new-git-user-using-netbeans-support-unable-to-pull-latest-commit-from-remote-rep

Comment: @Sherlock, were you able to get this to work?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: The link provided by @michas was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before any interaction with a remote repository (i.e. push or pull) have a look at `git status` and decide what to do with those "uncommitted changes". Either commit them if they introduce useful functionality or discard them if not. - A `git pull` might not be able to do its job if you still have "uncommitted changes".

Remember that a `git pull` is actually just a combination of `git fetch` which updates your remote branches and `git merge` which combines the corresponding remote branch into your current working tree. (That's why your git error talks about a failed merge.)

If you did not commit any changes on your side a `git pull` is always fine and just fast-forwards your working tree to the new version. If you did any commits and no one pushed to your remote branch everything is fine, too.

The only tricky part is, if you did some commits and someone else did other commits, too. In this case those branches diverted. `git fetch` will fetch the other changes and `git merge` will try to merge them with your work. This might work if you worked at other places in the code or might cause a conflict otherwise.